# Parametric curve $f(t)=(t^3-t, t^2-1)$

Tags: differential-geometry

I found this curve in a book:

$$f(t)=(t^3-t,t^2-1)$$ There is a picture of the trace but not much explanation on how they got there. Could anybody explain to me how to deduce what the trace of this curve is?

Comment: @Bye_World: Where did you find a $z$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x=ty$, so $t=x/y$, from which we see that $y=t^2-1=(\frac xy)^2 - 1$. Multiplying through by $y^2$, we have $y^3=x^2-y^2$ or $x^2=y^2(y+1)$. Now can you figure out how to graph this? (It's called a nodal cubic curve.)

By the way, the meaning of the parameter $t$ is that $1/t$ is the slope of the line through the origin to the point $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$ on the curve.

Comment: Why does this work? Just plugging in the value of t=x/y for the second coordinate? Also, is $x^2=y^2(y-1)$ an easy curve? I cant graph it.

Comment: It works because the nodal cubic curve has a double-point and can be parametrized by polynomial functions; this is a classic example. You realize that it looks like $y^2=x^2$ (so $|y|=|x|$) near the origin, but also crosses the $y$-axis at $(0,-1)$. For large $|x|$ it looks very much like $x=\pm y^{3/2}$. Note that we must have $y\ge -1$. (If you want, you can write $\pm x = \sqrt{y^3+y^2}$ and use standard calculus techniques to graph this.)

Comment: I think what is hard for me to understand is that $x^2=y^2(y-1)$ isn't a function, or is it?

Comment: Nope, it isn't ;) Good call.

Comment: If I separate cases then will it be a function?

Comment: That's why I wrote $x= \pm\sqrt{y^3+y^2}$ above. But you're used to equations like $x^2+y^2=1$, which don't represent functions either :P